# dired-do-rename throws file-error when changing upper/lower-case name

Tags: dired

I am using Emacs master branch built `--with-ns` on a drive that is case *insensitive* -- aka **Mac OS Extended (Journaled)**.  I would like to use `dired-do-rename` to change a folder name from upper to lower-case or visa-versa.  Emacs throws a `file-error` and does not change the name:

```
Move ‘/Volumes/STORAGE/PROGRAMS/HP_ScanJet_8290’ to ‘/Volumes/STORAGE/PROGRAMS/hp_scanjet_8290/HP_ScanJet_8290’ failed:

(file-error Renaming Invalid argument /Volumes/STORAGE/PROGRAMS/HP_ScanJet_8290 /Volumes/STORAGE/PROGRAMS/hp_scanjet_8290/HP_ScanJet_8290)
```

I am looking for some assistance, please, to redefine one or more of the `dired` functions to permit this operation to succeed.  The solution can certainly use `advice` (since most of the forum participants seem to prefer that method), however, a new function that replaces one or more existing functions is also acceptable.

---

**EDIT**:  The following is the output from `M-x debug-on-entry dired-do-create-files` after evaluating `(require 'dired-aux)`, and then trying to rename a folder [from CamelCase to all lower-case] using `S-r` in `dired-mode` -- aka `dired-do-rename`:

```
Debugger entered--entering a function:
  * dired-do-create-files(move dired-rename-file "Move" nil t "Rename")
    dired-do-rename(nil)
    funcall-interactively(dired-do-rename nil)
    call-interactively(dired-do-rename nil nil)
    command-execute(dired-do-rename)
```

---

**EDIT**:  This appears to be a bug affecting OSX users of Emacs and the appropriate thing to do (as Drew suggested) is file a bug report so that everyone can benefit from the fix -- instead of a fix that is only available on emacs.stackexchange.com.  Here is the link to the report:  http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=22300

---

**EDIT**:  The bug was summarily dismissed / closed in about 5 minutes flat with the following explanation:

```
Since this is not an Emacs bug, I'm closing this report, but here is what I do
that should work for you:

  1. Rename the file to 'x'.
  2. Rename 'x' to the correctly cased name.

Copy the name to the kill-ring before #1, so that you can paste it in when
asked by #2.
```

---

**[@lawlist (the original poster)]**:  The moral of the story is that this question remains open and any help to implement a proper bug fix for OSX users would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give a step-by-step recipe to repro the error? It looks like the first arg you gave is a directory and the second is a file in that directory (since the directory name differences are ignored by your OS).

Comment: Have you tried `M-x debug-on-entry dired-do-create-files` (after loading `dired-aux.el`, not `*.elc`)?

Comment: @Drew -- Thank you for the suggestion - I performed the test and edited the question with the output.  It's basically just a Shift+r on a folder that contains the name `HP_ScanJet_8290` and trying to change it to all lowercase.

Comment: I meant see what the debugger says happens in `dired-do-create-files` (not leading up to it). It's not clear what it is (you are) trying to rename to what. And see what I said about what appear to be your renaming args - the directory and file name being the same, etc.

Comment: Perhaps my problem with debugging is that I am improperly using `M-x debug-on-entry dired-do-create-files`?  I suppose I could open up `dired-do-create-files` and place a bunch of messages throughout and attempt to find out why the `file-error` is thrown, but that would be a lengthy process for later this evening . . .  Basically (i.e., *I guess*), on a case-insensitive drive the `file-error` happens if the same name is used when renaming because `dired` cannot distinguish any difference between CamelCase / UPPERCASE / lowercase.

Comment: Forget about debugging. Your question is not clear. On MS Windows (which is case-insensitive for folder names etc.) I can easily use `+` to create a new directory `FOO`, and then use `R` to rename it to `foo`. (Emacs asks me to confirm the renaming.) I can just as easily use `R` to rename it back to `FOO`. Describe what you do step by step (including the names).

Comment: @Drew -- Yes, you are describing the exact same test that fails on OSX.

Comment: Then consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. It might be an OSX problem, not an Emacs problem, but filing a bug report is a way to find out.

Comment: This looks horribly wrong to me, which is why I asked for a recipe: ***Move ‘/Volumes/STORAGE/PROGRAMS/HP_ScanJet_8290’ to ‘/Volumes/STORAGE/PROGRAMS/hp_scanjet_8290/HP_ScanJet_8290’ failed:*** That looks like you asked to rename that directory to a file of the same name within a lowercase version of the same directory. (??)

Comment: Yes, you are correct in that it appears to be a bug affecting OSX users.  OSX users would probably benefit if this were fixed in actual source code, instead of a bug fix that is only available on emacs.stackexchange.com.  I generally try to fix things myself where possible, but this particular bug is probably important enough that the Emacs team will want to incorporate its fix into the master branch and perhaps Emacs 25.  I'll update the question with the link to the Emacs bug report.

Comment: @Drew -- my bug was summarily dismissed/closed in about 5 minutes flat, with a suggested workaround -- e.g., rename `FOO` to `X` and then rename it to `foo`.  :)

Comment: Is `mv` command able to do what you were trying to do? From here it seems like it wouldn't (you'd need to create the all-lowercase directory first). I'm not sure if OSX allows file names to differ only in capitalization, but if it does, did you try creating the all-lowercase directory first?

Comment: @wvxvw -- yes, that works perfectly -- what a great suggestion! -- i.e., `mv FOO foo`.  Perhaps a simple modification of `dired` would be to test for the same name in all its forms of upper/lower/camel-case, and then call a `start-process` with `mv` if applicable, and the default behavior when the names are not the same.

Comment: Well, if you don't encounter this problem very often, you could simply type `!` on a file in `Dired` buffer and then tell it to `mv ? other-name`. This is almost as much typing as you would have done renaming it (provided you copied the file name to the buffer first, which you could do with `w`).

Comment: Both suggestions will work well -- thank you -- I'm tentatively going to make a permanent fix in my own setup that uses a test for `(eq system-type 'darwin)` and if the names are the same in all forms, then `start-process ... mv ...)`, else default behavior.

Comment: You could try `(defadvice dired-rename-file (around mv-for-equal-files activate)
  "Apply os-command mv if src and dst are equal." 
  (if (and ok-if-already-exists (file-equal-p file newname))
      (call-process "mv" nil nil nil file newname)
    ad-do-it))` But, I cannot test it because I am not on OSX. Please do not sue me when your computer blows up;-).

Comment: I sent a msg to the dismissed bug report. I don't see why Emacs seems to be asking to move `.../FOO` to `.../foo/FOO`. I don't understand how we can be certain that this is not an Emacs problem. But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: John Wiegley has reopened the Emacs bug ([#22300[(http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=22300)).

Comment: @Tobias -- now that the bug report has been reopened, I'm going to give the Emacs team a reasonable period of time to create an official patch/fix.  If after a reasonable period of time a patch/fix is not forthcoming, then I'll adopt a workaround.  I updated the bug report with a couple of additional pieces of information, one of which is that the destination/target gets garbled -- so your workaround won't work until that portion of the code within `dired-create-files` is fixed, or whatever portion of the C-source code is preventing the `elisp` from returning the correct destionation path.

Comment: Consider posting and accepting an answer saying that this is an Emacs bug etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the bug report is being handled by the Emacs team -- http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=22300 -- I am using the following workaround in the interim, which basically bypasses `dired-create-files` if the situation is as described in the original question above.  The workaround also reverts the buffer after the file has been renamed, instead of the fancy cut/paste of just the affected line that `dired-mode` normally does.

[The workaround was inspired by the helpful comment of @wvxvw underneath the original question -- i.e., using `mv` to rename the file.]

```lisp
(require 'dired-aux)

(require 'cl) ;; for `lexical-let*' to penetrate the `set-process-sentinel'.

(defun dired-do-create-files (op-symbol file-creator operation arg
                    &optional marker-char op1
                    how-to)
  "Create a new file for each marked file.
Prompt user for a target directory in which to create the new
  files.  The target may also be a non-directory file, if only
  one file is marked.  The initial suggestion for target is the
  Dired buffer's current directory (or, if `dired-dwim-target' is
  non-nil, the current directory of a neighboring Dired window).
OP-SYMBOL is the symbol for the operation.  Function `dired-mark-pop-up'
  will determine whether pop-ups are appropriate for this OP-SYMBOL.
FILE-CREATOR and OPERATION as in `dired-create-files'.
ARG as in `dired-get-marked-files'.
Optional arg MARKER-CHAR as in `dired-create-files'.
Optional arg OP1 is an alternate form for OPERATION if there is
  only one file.
Optional arg HOW-TO determines how to treat the target.
  If HOW-TO is nil, use `file-directory-p' to determine if the
   target is a directory.  If so, the marked file(s) are created
   inside that directory.  Otherwise, the target is a plain file;
   an error is raised unless there is exactly one marked file.
  If HOW-TO is t, target is always treated as a plain file.
  Otherwise, HOW-TO should be a function of one argument, TARGET.
   If its return value is nil, TARGET is regarded as a plain file.
   If it return value is a list, TARGET is a generalized
    directory (e.g. some sort of archive).  The first element of
    this list must be a function with at least four arguments:
      operation - as OPERATION above.
      rfn-list  - list of the relative names for the marked files.
      fn-list   - list of the absolute names for the marked files.
      target    - the name of the target itself.
      The rest of into-dir are optional arguments.
   For any other return value, TARGET is treated as a directory."
  (or op1 (setq op1 operation))
  (let* ((fn-list (dired-get-marked-files nil arg))
     (rfn-list (mapcar (function dired-make-relative) fn-list))
     (dired-one-file    ; fluid variable inside dired-create-files
      (and (consp fn-list) (null (cdr fn-list)) (car fn-list)))
     (target-dir (dired-dwim-target-directory))
     (default (and dired-one-file
               (expand-file-name (file-name-nondirectory (car fn-list))
                     target-dir)))
     (defaults (dired-dwim-target-defaults fn-list target-dir))
     (target (expand-file-name ; fluid variable inside dired-create-files
          (minibuffer-with-setup-hook
              (lambda ()
            (set (make-local-variable 'minibuffer-default-add-function) nil)
            (setq minibuffer-default defaults))
            (dired-mark-read-file-name
             (concat (if dired-one-file op1 operation) " %s to: ")
             target-dir op-symbol arg rfn-list default))))
     (into-dir (cond ((null how-to)
              ;; Allow DOS/Windows users to change the letter
              ;; case of a directory.  If we don't test these
              ;; conditions up front, file-directory-p below
              ;; will return t because the filesystem is
              ;; case-insensitive, and Emacs will try to move
              ;; foo -> foo/foo, which fails.
              (if (and (memq system-type '(ms-dos windows-nt cygwin))
                   (eq op-symbol 'move)
                   dired-one-file
                   (string= (downcase
                         (expand-file-name (car fn-list)))
                        (downcase
                         (expand-file-name target)))
                   (not (string=
                     (file-name-nondirectory (car fn-list))
                     (file-name-nondirectory target))))
                  nil
                (file-directory-p target)))
             ((eq how-to t) nil)
             (t (funcall how-to target)))))
    (if (and (consp into-dir) (functionp (car into-dir)))
    (apply (car into-dir) operation rfn-list fn-list target (cdr into-dir))
      (if (not (or dired-one-file into-dir))
      (error "Marked %s: target must be a directory: %s" operation target))
      ;; rename-file bombs when moving directories unless we do this:
      (or into-dir (setq target (directory-file-name target)))
;;; BEGIN modification by @lawlist
      (if
          (and
            (eq system-type 'darwin)
            dired-one-file
            (equal op1 "Rename")
            (equal operation "Move")
            (equal (downcase (expand-file-name dired-one-file)) (downcase (expand-file-name target))))
        ;; Penetrate the `set-process-sentinel' with `lexical-let'.
        (lexical-let* ((dired-one-file dired-one-file)
                       (target target))
          (set-process-sentinel
            (start-process "rename" nil "mv" dired-one-file target)
            (lambda (p e) (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
              (revert-buffer)
              (message "Renamed %s to %s" dired-one-file target)))))
      (dired-create-files
       file-creator operation fn-list
       (if into-dir         ; target is a directory
       ;; This function uses fluid variable target when called
       ;; inside dired-create-files:
       (function
        (lambda (from)
          (expand-file-name (file-name-nondirectory from) target)))
     (function (lambda (_from) target)))
       marker-char))
;;; END modification by @lawlist
  )))
```